# ¿Como pasar datos de un listview a una tabla en una BD SQL Server ? Visual Basic

Tags: sql-server, .net, listview, vb

Estoy haciendo un sistema de venta para un restaurant. Los productos que la gente ordena las ingreso en un ListView para posteriormente, al presionar un boton, se manden los datos del ListView a una tabla que tengo en SQL Server llamada "Orden".

Mi listview tiene los siguientes items:

---

ITEM...............SUB-ITEM1............. SUBITEM2

Producto..........  Cantidad ................... Precio

Wings.....................2 .........................$280

---

El problema que tengo es que no puedo hacer que mi programa mande los datos ingresados en mi Listview a mi tabla "Orden" en mi base de datos. Es decir, al presionar el boton para enviar los datos del listview a mi BD, en mi base de datos aparece el nuevo registro pero en blanco...como si mi listview estuviera vacio y ese vacio se hubiera mandado a la tabla. No se me explico bien...les dejo el codigo que se encarga de hacer esta tarea.

```
Public Sub ordenar()

    Dim producto As String = ""
    Dim cantidad As Integer
    Dim precio As Integer
    Dim i As Integer = 1
    Dim j As Integer = 1
    Dim k As Integer = 2

    Dim con As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.NAConnectionString)
    Dim insertarComida As New SqlDataAdapter("insert into orden values ('" & producto & "','" & cantidad & "','" & precio & "')", con)
    Dim dTableOrden As DataTable = New DataTable("orden")
    Dim dataset As DataSet = New DataSet("Orden")
    con.Open()


    While i <= Form6.ListView1.Items.Count - 1

        insertarComida.Fill(dataset)
        With Form6.ListView1

        producto = .Items(i).Text
        cantidad = .Items(i).SubItems(j).Text
        precio = .Items(i).SubItems(k).Text

        End With

        i += 1
    End While
End Sub
```

Espero que se entienda mi problema...de antemano gracias!

Comment: Lo primero que debes hacer es aprender a parametrizar tus instrucciones de SQL. De otro modo, estarás abierto a inyección de SQL y puedes poner en riesgo todo tu sistema.

Comment: Tal vez esto te ayude o alguien con conocimientos en VB.net pueda hacerlo. https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/net-framework/using-table-valued-parameters-with-vb-net/

Comment: El problema entiendo es al momento de la ejecución en el insert, y ojo que estas dejando conexiones abiertas.